# Catalyst App still showing Fund9 instead of Fund10 and connection in progress as of 26/6/2023

Tags: catalyst

The Catalyst App has not been updated since 2022 and gives only information about Fund9 as of June. When will the Fund10 voting round be available in the app and my wallet registration completed?

Answer (score 0):

Same question asked here (but with an answer):
https://forum.cardano.org/t/fund-10-registration/117712/5